# A bunch of errors when running npm install

Tags: npm, installation, error-log

When I run npm install on my xampp laravel setup I get a bunch of errors. log is LONG and shown below. I don't even know where to start

- I've tried deleting my node_module folder (that was a random guess, nothing changed)
- I've tried to run npm install -g (didn't work either)

I'm installing the root of my project and I've got a composer.json file.

Error log:

[Errorlog link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgAJtRXKFU2pk33ySf62YUnuZBNk?e=yFGwAS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just deleting the node-sass folder in node_modules (if it's there), then run `npm install node-sass@4.9.2 --save`, and run npm install again!

Comment: node_sass folder is not there - and the command

npm install node-sass@4.9.2 --save

Gave an equally great amount of errors.

Comment: So you did resolve my issue...

I did npm install node-sass@4.12.0 --save

And everything worked....

Thanks :)

Comment: Haha awesome glad it worked! Sorry I forgot about this and didn't provide further assistance